Translating a code from Athena SQL to Pyspark SQL
For some reason I have to translate an Athena SQL code to Pyspark SQL.
This thing is taking me too long because I don't know how to do it properly.
TRY(
    FILTER(
        ARRAY_AGG(
            ARRAY[dt, period_inactivity]
            ORDER BY date(dt) DESC
        ),
        x -> CAST(x[2] AS INTEGER) > 3
    )[1][1]
) AS last_comeback

Thank you.
I tried to put it like that, and I tried ChatGPT to do it for me but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea what it is meant to be doing? It would be hard for us to assist you without knowing.
